# Canvas moves using keyboard input but image does not

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

so I started with the basics adding canavs, css, javascript. should the image be in the html or javascript?
next i added a background color to the canvas. then i add canvas properties in javascript along with keyCodes. i got the image in with window.onload. after that i notice the canvas was moving but not the image.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("app");
canvas.width  = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";

var keys = [];

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
 keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
 delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

function game(){
 window.onload;
 update();
 render();
}

function update(){
 if(keys[38]) img.y--;
 if(keys[40]) img.y++;
 if(keys[37]) img.x--;
 if(keys[39]) img.x++;
}
function render(){
 ctx.fillRect(img.x, img.y);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById("app");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("chio");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
};

setInterval(function(){
    game();
}, 1000/30)


// > note: window.onload shows the images
```

```css
#app{
background-color:#33ff00
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="app" width=300 height=640></canvas>
<img id="chio" src="chio.png"/>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm lost at this point, please help me

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  Few people will be willing to dig through all that code.  It would also help to describe your problem more clearly with steps to reproduce it.

Comment: First at all you should declare the variable `c`, `ctx` and `img` outsite of the function, because in the render `function` are undefined. Then the function `fillRect` needs 4 parameters and you put only 2, then if you are more clear we can check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some correction in "app.js" but I don't know what do you want exactly. If you wanted to move the image then this is a way.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("app");
canvas.width  = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";

var keys = [];
var ctx;
var img;
var position = {x:0,y:0};
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}, false);

function game(){
    update();
    render();
}

function update(){
    if(keys[38]) position.y--;
    if(keys[40]) position.y++;
    if(keys[37]) position.x--;
    if(keys[39]) position.x++;
}
function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img,position.x,position.y);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById("app");
    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    img=document.getElementById("chio");
};

setInterval(function(){
    game();
}, 1000/30);


// > note: window.onload shows the images
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the code you've given, the most problematic being that you're trying to access DOM elements in various places potentially before the document has loaded. This should all be done attached to the `window.onload` event you're already using.

Another issue is that you're declaring variables locally and initializing them, but elsewhere in your code you treat them as global variables and try to access them - generating more errors. These variables should be moved to the global scope.

You're also trying to modify some x/y attribute on the original `<img>` element to track its position on the canvas - this won't work. I'd move the position tracking into a JavaScript object with x/y properties.

Lastly, you're not calling the correct code to draw the image to the canvas in your `render()` function. I'd suggest clearing the canvas and redrawing the image with `drawImage()`.

Putting all these suggestions to practice, your JavaScript becomes:

```
// Global variables for later use
var keys = [];
var canvas;
var ctx;
var img;

// Object to track image position on canvas
var imgPos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

function game(){
    window.onload;
    update();
    render();
}

function update(){
    if(keys[38]) imgPos.y--;
    if(keys[40]) imgPos.y++;
    if(keys[37]) imgPos.x--;
    if(keys[39]) imgPos.x++;
}
function render(){
    // Clear canvas and redraw image at new location
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img,imgPos.x,imgPos.y);
}

window.onload = function() {
    // Initialize canvas
    canvas = document.getElementById("app");
    canvas.width  = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
    canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";

    // Draw image to canvas
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    img=document.getElementById("chio");
    ctx.drawImage(img,imgPos.x,imgPos.y);

    // Start game loop
    setInterval(function(){
        game();
    }, 1000/30);
};
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph9s62se/4/) to demonstrate. I've commented the code wherever I made significant changes to help you follow it better. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.